# VSCode not auto-detecting grunt file

Tags: azure, gruntjs, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode 0.8 installed on windows 10, open to a folder. The grunt file at the root of this folder is named gruntfile.js (I also tried grunt.js). The grunt tasks work from the node cli but are not discovered inside VSCode.

I've tried ctrl+shift+p, then 'run task deploy-to-azure' where the task name in the grunt file is deploy-to-azure.

How is the grunt file auto-detected? Is there a way to turn on error reporting in VSCode or a log file I could review to see what is happening? Or perhaps an enumeration of all grunt, gulp, jake tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed I did this in .vscode/tasks.json and it all works OK for me.  I did have to reboot because I lost grunt during the upgrade somehow.

```
// A task runner configuration.
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent"
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        /*  "problemMatcher": "$lessCompile" */
        },
        {
            "taskName": "test",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": false,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always"
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        /*  "problemMatcher": "$lessCompile" */
        },
        {
            "taskName": "localhost",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": false,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always"
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        /*  "problemMatcher": "$lessCompile" */
        }
    ]
}
```